# Extractor function for "call" in lm

Tags: r

Is there a generic extractor function for linear models to pull the *call* from the model? I'm looking to apply a model across a list of dataframes, then extract the call for that model (I'm doing this a bunch of times over many data frames and models, so looking for an easy way to keep track of which model is which)

Example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(plyr)
    data <- data.frame(
        biz = sample(c("telco","shipping","tech"), 50, replace = TRUE),
        region = sample(c("mideast","americas"), 50, replace = TRUE),
        orders = sample(1:50, 50, replace=TRUE),
        revenue = sample(100:150, 50, replace=TRUE)
        )
```

Now if I wanted to apply a simple lm across this data, by "region" :

```
modlist <- dlply(data, 'region', function(df){
    summary(lm(revenue ~ orders, data=df))
    })
```

For something that has a standard extractor function, like "coefficients" = "coef", this is straightforward:

```
coefs <- ldply(modlist, coef)
```

But I can't find any way to extract the "call", e.g., "lm(formula = revenue ~ orders, data = df)". Any ideas?

Comment: You can find the call in `lm`  For example `lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)$call` or in `summary(model)$call`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your own function to extract the call in the same way `stats:::print.lm` does

```
coefs <- ldply(modlist, function(x) deparse(x$call))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[[`:

```
lapply(modlist, "[[", "call")
# $americas
# lm(formula = revenue ~ orders, data = df)
# 
# $mideast
# lm(formula = revenue ~ orders, data = df)
```